# Crystal Reports 2016: New Field limiting Record Returns

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with Fields firstname, middlename, lastname, and doctorappointmentdate. All of these fields are Not Null on the backend; and there is a one to many relationship to the person entitiy and the doctorappointment entity. So, the report is grouped by person, to show multiple doctorappointmentdate(s).

Sometimes, the person has a comment/complaint about a doctor. So, I have to add  complaintnumber to the report.

When I added the complaint number to the report, it only returns records with a complaint number; and complaintnumber can be null.

How can I get the full list of people, whether or not they have a complaint number?

Comment: Make sure it is a left join and not an inner join to the new table

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was an inner join, I changed it to an left outer join; but that didn't work. I think I'm going to keep it as an left outer.

Maybe some other additional information can help with this; sorry I'm not too familiar with Crystal Reports to know what type of information to include. But, in the Format Editor, Common tab; none of the options are selected. (Read-only, Suppress, Suppress If Duplicated, Lock Position and Size)

Comment: This is really confusing, because the query itself has not changed; the only thing is that we're adding another field from a table that is already there.

Comment: if you remove the field, it works again?

Comment: I think I found it. In the database query, there's a conditional LIKE for the last name. Now, all I have to do is figure out how to update the database query and get that out of there.

Comment: @KalaNag Yes, it works again.